# Function to switch between banners with infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code below, it performs a function to switch between banners and also has an infinity loop to switch. but when doing the transition between banners. it appears one more banner like the original banner then switch to another banner.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const banners = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-banner');
const toggleLeft = document.querySelector('.slider-toggle-left');
const toggleRight = document.querySelector('.slider-toggle-right');
let currentBanner = 0;
const firstBannerClone = banners[0].cloneNode(true);
slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').appendChild(firstBannerClone);

function switchBanner(direction) {
  if (direction === 'left') {
    // console.log("a."+ currentBanner);
    currentBanner--;
    // console.log("b."+ currentBanner);
    if (currentBanner < 0) {
      // console.log("1."+ banners.length);
      currentBanner = banners.length;
      slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transition = 'none';
      slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transform = `translateX(-${(banners.length) * 100}%)`;
      // console.log("c."+ currentBanner);
      setTimeout(() => {
        slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-out';
        currentBanner = banners.length - 1;
        slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transform = `translateX(-${currentBanner * 100}%)`;
        // console.log("d."+ currentBanner);
      }, 50);
    }
  } else if (direction === 'right') {
    // console.log("a."+ currentBanner);
    currentBanner++;
    // console.log("b."+ currentBanner);
    if (currentBanner > banners.length) {
      // console.log("1."+ banners.length);
      currentBanner = 0;
      slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transition = 'none';
      slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transform = `translateX(-${currentBanner * 100}%)`;
      // console.log("c."+ currentBanner);
      setTimeout(() => {
        slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-out';
        currentBanner = 1;
        slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transform = `translateX(-${currentBanner * 100}%)`;
        // console.log("d."+ currentBanner);
      }, 50);
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
  slider.querySelector('.slider-banners').style.transform = `translateX(-${currentBanner * 100}%)`;
}
toggleLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchBanner('left');
});
toggleRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchBanner('right');
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-banners {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider-banner {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.slider-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.slider-toggle:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.slider-toggle-left {
  left: 0;
}

.slider-toggle-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-banners">
    <div class="slider-banner red">red</div>
    <div class="slider-banner blue">blue</div>
    <div class="slider-banner green">green</div>
  </div>
  <button class="slider-toggle slider-toggle-left">&#8249;</button>
  <button class="slider-toggle slider-toggle-right">&#8250;</button>
</div>
```

Can you help me fix it or is there another way I can make it better?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself? Also, consider not using an infinite loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.